# Mac Pro Tower Repeatedly hanging/rebooting. Mint clean install with zero internet time

Tags: performance, mac-pro, kernel-panic

Hardware 5,1. 
I have replaced the power supply once.  Machine keeps either rebooting or display the "your mac has a problem and needs to reboot screen". This is on a largely mint OSX and audio app reinstall. Zero internet connection time on this machine.

Here follows the one of the crash reports.
I believe the machine doesn't have a good serial number installed in the firmware due to previous work done. This is causing a lot of authentication errors in the internal messaging system but was not a rebooting problem previous. I recently upgraded to high sierra and the problems commenced 3 days later.  The machine was running like a dream for those 3 days!!

```
Anonymous UUID:       BAA29220-A235-CC33-5459-DE9FA9D2F44C

Wed Sep 26 10:56:39 2018

*** Panic Report ***
Machine-check capabilities: 0x0000000000001c09
 family: 6 model: 44 stepping: 2 microcode: 30
 signature: 0x206c2
 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5650  @ 2.67GHz
 9 error-reporting banks
Processor 0: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000004
 IA32_MC8_STATUS(0x421): 0xfe0000000001009f
 IA32_MC8_ADDR(0x422):   0x00000001702b2f40
 IA32_MC8_MISC(0x423):   0x88f6377e00041081
Processor 1: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000004
 IA32_MC8_STATUS(0x421): 0xfe0000000001009f
 IA32_MC8_ADDR(0x422):   0x00000001702b2f40
 IA32_MC8_MISC(0x423):   0x88f6377e00041081
Processor 2: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000004
 IA32_MC8_STATUS(0x421): 0xfe0000000001009f
 IA32_MC8_ADDR(0x422):   0x00000001702b2f40
 IA32_MC8_MISC(0x423):   0x88f6377e00041081
Processor 3: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000004
 IA32_MC8_STATUS(0x421): 0xfe0000000001009f
 IA32_MC8_ADDR(0x422):   0x00000001702b2f40
 IA32_MC8_MISC(0x423):   0x88f6377e00041081
Processor 4: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000004
 IA32_MC8_STATUS(0x421): 0xfe0000000001009f
 IA32_MC8_ADDR(0x422):   0x00000001702b2f40
 IA32_MC8_MISC(0x423):   0x88f6377e00041081
Processor 5: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000004
 IA32_MC8_STATUS(0x421): 0xfe0000000001009f
 IA32_MC8_ADDR(0x422):   0x00000001702b2f40
 IA32_MC8_MISC(0x423):   0x88f6377e00041081
Processor 6: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000004
 IA32_MC8_STATUS(0x421): 0xfe0000000001009f
 IA32_MC8_ADDR(0x422):   0x00000001702b2f40
 IA32_MC8_MISC(0x423):   0x88f6377e00041081
Processor 7: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000004
 IA32_MC8_STATUS(0x421): 0xfe0000000001009f
 IA32_MC8_ADDR(0x422):   0x00000001702b2f40
 IA32_MC8_MISC(0x423):   0x88f6377e00041081
Processor 8: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000004
 IA32_MC8_STATUS(0x421): 0xfe0000000001009f
 IA32_MC8_ADDR(0x422):   0x00000001702b2f40
 IA32_MC8_MISC(0x423):   0x88f6377e00041081
Processor 9: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000004
 IA32_MC8_STATUS(0x421): 0xfe0000000001009f
 IA32_MC8_ADDR(0x422):   0x00000001702b2f40
 IA32_MC8_MISC(0x423):   0x88f6377e00041081
Processor 10: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000004
 IA32_MC8_STATUS(0x421): 0xfe0000000001009f
 IA32_MC8_ADDR(0x422):   0x00000001702b2f40
 IA32_MC8_MISC(0x423):   0x88f6377e00041081
Processor 11: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000004
 IA32_MC8_STATUS(0x421): 0xfe0000000001009f
 IA32_MC8_ADDR(0x422):   0x00000001702b2f40
 IA32_MC8_MISC(0x423):   0x88f6377e00041081
mp_kdp_enter(): 3839, 1, 12 TIMED-OUT WAITING FOR NMI-ACK, PROCEEDING
panic(cpu 8 caller 0xffffff801838811a): "Machine Check at 0xffffff801838dda1, registers:\n" "CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x00007fff4b244e04, CR3: 0x000000001bf33000, CR4: 0x00000000000226e0\n" "RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0x0000000000000003, RCX: 0x00000000603d98dd, RDX: 0x0000000000000000\n" "RSP: 0xffffff80b1a2bd10, RBP: 0xffffff80b1a2bd10, RSI: 0x0000000000000002, RDI: 0x0000000000000200\n" "R8:  0xffffff8024881c00, R9:  0x00000000f9896bcb, R10: 0x0000000000000000, R11: 0xffffff801f6618b0\n" "R12: 0x00000000f98e458d, R13: 0x7fffffffffffffff, R14: 0x7fffffffffffffff, R15: 0xffffff7f9b2cc9f8\n" "RFL: 0x0000000000000016, RIP: 0xffffff801838dda1, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010\n" "Error code: 0x0000000000000000\n"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-4570.71.2/osfmk/i386/trap_native.c:168
Backtrace (CPU 8), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8018150330 : 0xffffff801826c1c6 
0xffffff8018150380 : 0xffffff8018395274 
0xffffff80181503c0 : 0xffffff8018387544 
0xffffff8018150430 : 0xffffff801821e1e0 
0xffffff8018150450 : 0xffffff801826bc3c 
0xffffff8018150580 : 0xffffff801826b9fc 
0xffffff80181505e0 : 0xffffff801838811a 
0xffffff80181506d0 : 0xffffff801821ea5f 
0xffffff80b1a2bd10 : 0xffffff801838f4e3 
0xffffff80b1a2bd20 : 0xffffff7f9b2aeeb1 
0xffffff80b1a2bd50 : 0xffffff7f9b2aef61 
0xffffff80b1a2bd90 : 0xffffff7f9b2a8a20 
0xffffff80b1a2be60 : 0xffffff7f9b2a7fe9 
0xffffff80b1a2bf10 : 0xffffff801838934c 
0xffffff80b1a2bf30 : 0xffffff801828a4a2 
0xffffff80b1a2bf80 : 0xffffff801828aa70 
0xffffff80b1a2bfa0 : 0xffffff801821d557 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement(220.50.1)[9D594B5E-4A7C-37DD-90E9-16DDBDA6C758]@0xffffff7f9b2a6000->0xffffff7f9b2cffff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
17G65

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 17.7.0: Thu Jun 21 22:53:14 PDT 2018; root:xnu-4570.71.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 1AE5ACFD-3B6F-3D74-AD52-31F1430DBC6F
Kernel slide:     0x0000000018000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8018200000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8018100000
System model name: MacPro5,1 (Mac-F221BEC8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 5190132173
last loaded kext at 3241294196: com.apple.filesystems.apfs  748.51.0 (addr 0xffffff7f999aa000, size 999424)
loaded kexts:
com.Accusys.driver.Acxxx    3.5.3
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  748.51.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 1.0
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.50.6
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.9
com.apple.driver.Intel82574LEthernet    2.7.2
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  329.50.2
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 220.50.1
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   183
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   220.50.1
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  301.40.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio  312.6
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   206.5
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.7.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBUHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBUHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIParallelFamily    3.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    439.70.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  140.70.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   404.30.2
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 480.60.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    680.15
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1

EOF
Model: MacPro5,1, BootROM MP51.0089.B00, 6 processors, 6-Core Intel Xeon, 2.66 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.39f11
Graphics: ATI Radeon HD 5770, ATI Radeon HD 5770, PCIe
Memory Module: DIMM 1, 2 GB, DDR3 ECC, 1333 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54313235553754465238432D48392020
Memory Module: DIMM 2, 2 GB, DDR3 ECC, 1333 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54313235553754465238432D48392020
PCI Card: ATI Radeon HD 5770, Display Controller, Slot-1
PCI Card: pci1b73,1100, USB eXtensible Host Controller, Slot-2@10,0,0
PCI Card: pci1b73,1100, USB eXtensible Host Controller, Slot-2@9,0,0
PCI Card: pci1b73,1100, USB eXtensible Host Controller, Slot-2@11,0,0
PCI Card: pci1b73,1100, USB eXtensible Host Controller, Slot-2@8,0,0
Serial ATA Device: KINGSTON SA400S37480G, 480.1 GB
USB Device: USB Bus
USB Device: USB Bus
USB Device: USB Bus
USB Device: USB Bus
USB Device: USB Bus
USB Device: USB Bus
USB Device: iLok
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
USB Device: Kensington Slimblade Trackball
USB Device: PreSonus FP8
USB Device: USB Keyboard
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Patriot Memory
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: USB3.0 Hub
USB Device: USB3.0 Hub
USB Device: USB3.0 Hub
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
USB Device: Fireface UFX (23688286)
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
FireWire Device: built-in_hub, Up to 800 Mb/sec
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

---

```
Anonymous UUID:       BAA29220-A235-CC33-5459-DE9FA9D2F44C

Wed Sep 26 10:56:39 2018

*** Panic Report ***
Machine-check capabilities: 0x0000000000001c09
 family: 6 model: 44 stepping: 2 microcode: 30
 signature: 0x206c2
 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5650  @ 2.67GHz
 9 error-reporting banks
Processor 0: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000004
 IA32_MC8_STATUS(0x421): 0xfe0000000001009f
 IA32_MC8_ADDR(0x422):   0x00000001702b2f40
 IA32_MC8_MISC(0x423):   0x88f6377e00041081
Processor 1: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000004
 IA32_MC8_STATUS(0x421): 0xfe0000000001009f
 IA32_MC8_ADDR(0x422):   0x00000001702b2f40
 IA32_MC8_MISC(0x423):   0x88f6377e00041081
Processor 2: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000004
 IA32_MC8_STATUS(0x421): 0xfe0000000001009f
 IA32_MC8_ADDR(0x422):   0x00000001702b2f40
 IA32_MC8_MISC(0x423):   0x88f6377e00041081
Processor 3: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000004
 IA32_MC8_STATUS(0x421): 0xfe0000000001009f
 IA32_MC8_ADDR(0x422):   0x00000001702b2f40
 IA32_MC8_MISC(0x423):   0x88f6377e00041081
Processor 4: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000004
 IA32_MC8_STATUS(0x421): 0xfe0000000001009f
 IA32_MC8_ADDR(0x422):   0x00000001702b2f40
 IA32_MC8_MISC(0x423):   0x88f6377e00041081
Processor 5: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000004
 IA32_MC8_STATUS(0x421): 0xfe0000000001009f
 IA32_MC8_ADDR(0x422):   0x00000001702b2f40
 IA32_MC8_MISC(0x423):   0x88f6377e00041081
Processor 6: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000004
 IA32_MC8_STATUS(0x421): 0xfe0000000001009f
 IA32_MC8_ADDR(0x422):   0x00000001702b2f40
 IA32_MC8_MISC(0x423):   0x88f6377e00041081
Processor 7: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000004
 IA32_MC8_STATUS(0x421): 0xfe0000000001009f
 IA32_MC8_ADDR(0x422):   0x00000001702b2f40
 IA32_MC8_MISC(0x423):   0x88f6377e00041081
Processor 8: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000004
 IA32_MC8_STATUS(0x421): 0xfe0000000001009f
 IA32_MC8_ADDR(0x422):   0x00000001702b2f40
 IA32_MC8_MISC(0x423):   0x88f6377e00041081
Processor 9: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000004
 IA32_MC8_STATUS(0x421): 0xfe0000000001009f
 IA32_MC8_ADDR(0x422):   0x00000001702b2f40
 IA32_MC8_MISC(0x423):   0x88f6377e00041081
Processor 10: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000004
 IA32_MC8_STATUS(0x421): 0xfe0000000001009f
 IA32_MC8_ADDR(0x422):   0x00000001702b2f40
 IA32_MC8_MISC(0x423):   0x88f6377e00041081
Processor 11: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000004
 IA32_MC8_STATUS(0x421): 0xfe0000000001009f
 IA32_MC8_ADDR(0x422):   0x00000001702b2f40
 IA32_MC8_MISC(0x423):   0x88f6377e00041081
mp_kdp_enter(): 3839, 1, 12 TIMED-OUT WAITING FOR NMI-ACK, PROCEEDING
panic(cpu 8 caller 0xffffff801838811a): "Machine Check at 0xffffff801838dda1, registers:\n" "CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x00007fff4b244e04, CR3: 0x000000001bf33000, CR4: 0x00000000000226e0\n" "RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0x0000000000000003, RCX: 0x00000000603d98dd, RDX: 0x0000000000000000\n" "RSP: 0xffffff80b1a2bd10, RBP: 0xffffff80b1a2bd10, RSI: 0x0000000000000002, RDI: 0x0000000000000200\n" "R8:  0xffffff8024881c00, R9:  0x00000000f9896bcb, R10: 0x0000000000000000, R11: 0xffffff801f6618b0\n" "R12: 0x00000000f98e458d, R13: 0x7fffffffffffffff, R14: 0x7fffffffffffffff, R15: 0xffffff7f9b2cc9f8\n" "RFL: 0x0000000000000016, RIP: 0xffffff801838dda1, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010\n" "Error code: 0x0000000000000000\n"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-4570.71.2/osfmk/i386/trap_native.c:168
Backtrace (CPU 8), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8018150330 : 0xffffff801826c1c6 
0xffffff8018150380 : 0xffffff8018395274 
0xffffff80181503c0 : 0xffffff8018387544 
0xffffff8018150430 : 0xffffff801821e1e0 
0xffffff8018150450 : 0xffffff801826bc3c 
0xffffff8018150580 : 0xffffff801826b9fc 
0xffffff80181505e0 : 0xffffff801838811a 
0xffffff80181506d0 : 0xffffff801821ea5f 
0xffffff80b1a2bd10 : 0xffffff801838f4e3 
0xffffff80b1a2bd20 : 0xffffff7f9b2aeeb1 
0xffffff80b1a2bd50 : 0xffffff7f9b2aef61 
0xffffff80b1a2bd90 : 0xffffff7f9b2a8a20 
0xffffff80b1a2be60 : 0xffffff7f9b2a7fe9 
0xffffff80b1a2bf10 : 0xffffff801838934c 
0xffffff80b1a2bf30 : 0xffffff801828a4a2 
0xffffff80b1a2bf80 : 0xffffff801828aa70 
0xffffff80b1a2bfa0 : 0xffffff801821d557 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement(220.50.1)[9D594B5E-4A7C-37DD-90E9-16DDBDA6C758]@0xffffff7f9b2a6000->0xffffff7f9b2cffff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
17G65

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 17.7.0: Thu Jun 21 22:53:14 PDT 2018; root:xnu-4570.71.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 1AE5ACFD-3B6F-3D74-AD52-31F1430DBC6F
Kernel slide:     0x0000000018000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8018200000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8018100000
System model name: MacPro5,1 (Mac-F221BEC8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 5190132173
last loaded kext at 3241294196: com.apple.filesystems.apfs  748.51.0 (addr 0xffffff7f999aa000, size 999424)
loaded kexts:
com.Accusys.driver.Acxxx    3.5.3
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  748.51.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 1.0
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.50.6
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.9
com.apple.driver.Intel82574LEthernet    2.7.2
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  329.50.2
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 220.50.1
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   183
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   220.50.1
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  301.40.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio  312.6
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   206.5
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.7.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBUHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBUHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIParallelFamily    3.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    439.70.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  140.70.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   404.30.2
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 480.60.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    680.15
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1

EOF
Model: MacPro5,1, BootROM MP51.0089.B00, 6 processors, 6-Core Intel Xeon, 2.66 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.39f11
Graphics: ATI Radeon HD 5770, ATI Radeon HD 5770, PCIe
Memory Module: DIMM 1, 2 GB, DDR3 ECC, 1333 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54313235553754465238432D48392020
Memory Module: DIMM 2, 2 GB, DDR3 ECC, 1333 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54313235553754465238432D48392020
PCI Card: ATI Radeon HD 5770, Display Controller, Slot-1
PCI Card: pci1b73,1100, USB eXtensible Host Controller, Slot-2@10,0,0
PCI Card: pci1b73,1100, USB eXtensible Host Controller, Slot-2@9,0,0
PCI Card: pci1b73,1100, USB eXtensible Host Controller, Slot-2@11,0,0
PCI Card: pci1b73,1100, USB eXtensible Host Controller, Slot-2@8,0,0
Serial ATA Device: KINGSTON SA400S37480G, 480.1 GB
USB Device: USB Bus
USB Device: USB Bus
USB Device: USB Bus
USB Device: USB Bus
USB Device: USB Bus
USB Device: USB Bus
USB Device: iLok
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
USB Device: Kensington Slimblade Trackball
USB Device: PreSonus FP8
USB Device: USB Keyboard
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Patriot Memory
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: USB3.0 Hub
USB Device: USB3.0 Hub
USB Device: USB3.0 Hub
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
USB Device: Fireface UFX (23688286)
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
FireWire Device: built-in_hub, Up to 800 Mb/sec
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Comment: I'd update the Accusys; or remove it altogether for testing. 3rd party kexts are always prime suspects. Also, test safe boot & using a fresh admin account; or fresh install on a spare drive.

Comment: i recently removed half the RAM and saw much less of a problem with hangs but its still happening...What is the Accusys? Is it the usb3.0 adapter?? Problem exists with it installed and with it removed.

Comment: Does my crash report have any specific indication of what the problem is?

Comment: This is looking like it's CPU related; though I would thoroughly test the RAM first.  Do this by removing ALL RAM (not just half) and only booting with a single stick.  If you can get a hold of known good RAM, even better.

Comment: I will try although I thought RAM must be installed in pairs...  I am considering a costly CPU upgrade but need to know the rest of the machine is OK before pulling the trigger.

Comment: [Accusys](http://www.accusys.com.tw/Support/download/) is RAID support. Following what Alan said, I'd run a full hardware test too. The Mac Pros shouldn't fall over with bad RAM necessarily, as they use ECC which is more resilient. I ran one for a year with a bad stick, which the machine would periodically shut the stick down & warn me about ;-) What I would do, for the sake of a couple of bucks, is replace the PRAM Battery. Had lots of weird issues on ones with a less-than-optimal battery.

Comment: BTW, if you're considering investing more in the machine, note you will need a new GPU before you can upgrade to Mojave - https://support.apple.com/HT208898

Comment: high sierra has this weird lockdown on sys files.. I can't boot into recovery because of a forgotten firmware password. I only managed to install high sierra from USB by playing the change number of ram chips game.. I should really blow out that password and get a definitive firmware serial installed.. Any guidance on this for my particular machine? I've already done it on my laptop using a Raspberry PI.....

Comment: That would be a separate question, really.